# ASP.NET MVC - Encapsulando Razor en una sola linea de código

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

como puedo crear partes de códigos Razor que sean reutilizables en todas mis vistas, llamando con una sola linea.
Tengo el siguiente escenario, todos mis modelos tienen los campos a, b, c y d y todas las vistas tienen una una parte que hace correspondencia a estos 4 atributos (a,b, c y d), claramente todos mis vistas tienen la mism porción de código, lo que yo quiero hacer es ponerlo en una Vista aparte y poderla llamarla algo así:

Crear la porción de vista

```
@PorcionVistaPersonalizada()
{
    @html.editfor...
    @html.displayfor...
    @foreach(....
    {
       .........
    }
}
```

y en mi vista primeria podría incluir el código simplemente llamándolo como algo así:

```
...
@PorcionVistaPersonalizada()
...
```

Ya revise Vistas parciales, pero las vistas parciales tienen que ser creadas por un control acción y necesitan sus propios datos (no agarran automáticamente la data del modelo de la vista primaria).
Ya revise algo de herlpers personalizados pero creo que los ejemplos son muy simples y si quiero hacer algo de combos tablas y demás se complica demasiado.

Bueno espero sus comentarios y gracias de antemano

Comment: Cuando creas un nuevo proyecto, hay una vista que se llama _layout.cshtml en la carpeta de shared, modifica esa vista para agregar tu codigo de razor y ahi mismo cargas tus CSS o los scripts que necesites para todas tus paginas.

Comment: Desesperante el sistema de puntuación de stackoverflow, que para que puedas poner una respuesta acertada como la de @AlaynCarreraArvizu tenga que ser en un comentario en vez de su lugar correspondiente..

Comment: Has mirado los Helpers? https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-pages/overview/ui-layouts-and-themes/creating-and-using-a-helper-in-an-aspnet-web-pages-site

Answer (score 1):

De hecho sí  que se puede hacer mediante vistas parciales, no necesitas usar el controlador y puedes pasarle la información del modelo que necesites.

1. Crea una vista parcial e incluye tu código a reutilizar. Ponle un nombre que te ayude a identificarla fácilmente, por ejemplo **_form**:

   ```
   @html.editfor...
   @html.displayfor...
   @foreach(....
   {
      .........
   }
   ```
2. Define dentro de la vista parcial el `@model` que vayas a utilizar. Puede ser un objeto genérico:

   ```
   @model object
   @html.editorFor...
   ```

   (Después podrás hacer *unboxing* al modelo: `MiModelo m = (MiModelo)Model;`) o bien podrá ser directamente del modelo que quieras:

   ```
   @model MiModelo
   @html.editorFor...
   ```
3. Cuando quieras incluir el código en otra vista solo tendrás que escribir:

   ```
   @Html.Partial("_form", Model)
   ```

   o si está en una carpeta de vistas distinta:

   ```
   @Html.Partial("~/Views/partial/_form.cshtml", Model)
   ```

   incluso puedes pasarle cualquier objeto, como por ejemplo alguna `ViewBag` o `ViewData`:

   ```
   @Html.Partial("~/Views/partial/_form.cshtml", ViewData["Dato1"])
   ```

   siendo el segundo parámetro el `@model` que recibirá la vista parcial, por lo tanto puedes llamar a sus propiedades con el objeto `Model` como en las vistas normales.

Así tendrás una vista parcial reutilizable donde quieras **sin necesidad de un controlador para invocarla** y utilizando el modelo que quieras. Yo llegué a un escenario donde el modelo de la vista parcial era un arreglo de objetos genéricos `object[]` y sigue funcionando a día de hoy.

Answer (score 0):

A mi parecer creo que esto se puede resolver utilizando una vista maestra,la cual puedan consumir las otras vistas que tienen los campos a, b, c, y d. Estos campos se pueden pasar a la vista maestra utilizando el ViewBag.

**Ejemplo de código de vista maestra**

```
<html>
  <head>

   <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>

    @* ... Cargar estilos de la vista maestra ... *@
    @* ... Aqui los estilos ... *@

    @* ... Cargar estilos de la vista que hace uso de la vista maestra ... *@
    @RenderSection("Styles", required: false)

  </head>

  <body>

  @* ... Aqui organizas los campos pasados mediante el ViewBag a tu gusto ... *@
  <div>@ViewBag.CampoA</div>
  <div>@ViewBag.CampoB</div>
  <div>@ViewBag.CampoC</div>
  <div>@ViewBag.CampoD</div>

  @* ... Aqui cargas la vista que hace uso de la vista maestra... *@
  @RenderBody()

  </body>

   @* ... Cargar scripts de la vista maestra ... *@
   @* ... Aqui los scripts ... *@

   @* ... Cargar scripts de la vista que hace uso de la vista maestra ... *@
   @RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)

  </body>
</html>
```

**Ejemplo de código de vista que hace uso de la vista maestra**

```
@{
   ViewBag.Title = "Tu titulo aqui";
   ViewBag.CampoA = "Valor de A";
   ViewBag.CampoB = "Valor de B";
   ViewBag.CampoC = "Valor de C";
   ViewBag.CampoD = "Valor de D";
   Layout = "~/Views/Main/VistaMaestra.cshtml"; //<--  Ruta de la vista maestra
}

@* ... Aquí pones el contenido html que quieras ... *@

@section Styles
{
   <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="@Url.Content("~/Content/css/tustilo.css")" />
   <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="@Url.Content("~/Content/css/tustilo.css")" />
   <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="@Url.Content("~/Content/css/tustilo.css")" />
}

@section Scripts
{
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/../tuscripts.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/../tuscripts.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
}
```

Espero que esta información te sea útil, como lo fue para mi

Saludos